# SQL Split column into multiple columns with key:value pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a table with rows containing ID, Name and Data. The Data column has multiple key/value pairs. I need to create a view that convert this Data column into multiple columns with the assigned column name.

Note: The extra columns are known: Age, Sex, Height and Weight. But rows can have any number of key/value pairs in them (from none to 4).

The value of each column could either be int or string.

For example my original table look like this:

```
ID   Name      Data
------------------------------------------------
1    John      Age=15;Sex=M;Height=172;Weight=56
2    Jane      Age=20;Height=176;
3    William   Age=32;Sex=M;Weight=77
4    Dan       Age=10
5    Steven    null
```

I need a view with output like this:

```
ID   Name      Age   Sex    Height  Weight
------------------------------------------
1    John      15    M      172     56
2    Jane      20    null   176     null 
3    William   32    M      null    77
4    Dan       10    null   null    null
5    Steven    null  null   null    null
```

Can someone please help me with some SQL code to achieve this view?

Thank you!

Comment: I would strongly recommend you normalize your data at least to 1NF. Text processing on the fly is expensive and produces very slow queries.

Comment: I hope this data is a result of consuming something that's been provided like that and not stored like it "by design". I doubt anyone will offer an ansi sql solution so you might want to consider reading [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759)

Comment: Thanks @Stu and TheImpaler for your comments. You are right Stu, this data is a result of other legacy applications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No time to do it for ANSI sql, but here a solution for ORACLE:

```
WITH data(id, name, vals) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'John', 'Age=15;Sex=M;Height=172;Weight=56' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Jane', 'Age=20;Height=176' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'William', 'Age=32;Sex=M;Weight=77' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 'Dan', 'Age=10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 'Steven', null FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id, name, t.*
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, '{' || LISTAGG(js, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lvl) || '}' AS js FROM (
        SELECT id, name, lvl, 
            NVL2(keyval,'"' || SUBSTR(keyval,1,INSTR(keyval,'=')-1) || '":"' || SUBSTR(keyval,INSTR(keyval,'=')+1) || '"',NULL) AS js
        FROM (
            SELECT id, name, LEVEL AS lvl, regexp_substr( vals, '[^;]+', 1, level) AS keyval
            FROM data
            CONNECT BY regexp_substr( vals, '[^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL AND PRIOR id = id AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
    GROUP BY id, name
) d,
JSON_TABLE(
    d.js,
    '$'
    columns (
        age NUMBER(10,0) PATH '$.Age',
        sex NUMBER(10,0) PATH '$.Sex',
        height NUMBER(10,0) PATH '$.Height',
        weight NUMBER(10,0) PATH '$.Weight'
    )
) t
;


1   John    15      172 56
2   Jane    20      176 
3   William 32          77
4   Dan 10          
5   Steven
```

Comment: Hi @p3consulting, thank you for your help. However, I forgot to mention, I need to run my code in MSSQL. Thanks.

Comment: Should be possible to convert to MSSQL using recursive CTE, STRING_AGG and the JSON techniques of MSSQL to convert the JSON into a table should work since we don't use dynamic names for columns.